# How to store a secret key from the given byte in the AndroidKeystore?

Tags: android, keystore

I want to import a secret key which is generated from the given byte array to Android Keystore. But some exception is raised .

Does anyone know how to import a secret key in this situation?

I tried below code :

```
try {
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte {0x31,0x32,0x33};
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            ks.load(null);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(signingKey);
            ks.setEntry("my_key", entry,
                    new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN).build());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception is as below:

```
W/System.err: java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to import secret key. Keystore error code: -6 
W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.setSecretKeyEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:742)

W/System.err:     at
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineSetEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:1060)
W/System.err:     at
 java.security.KeyStore.setEntry(KeyStore.java:1596)
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the issue by making sure the length of bytes array is supported by keystore.

The below is my modified code that works for now

```
     try {
            //32bytes (256bit)
            byte[] keyBytes = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            ks.load(null);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(signingKey);
            ks.setEntry("my_key", entry,
                    new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN).build());
     } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();        
     }
```